# CoreText. What is the Best Approach for Inputting Text Layout Information to a CoreText-based App?

Tags: xml, ios, plist, core-text

Our upcoming app will make extensive use of CoreText. Currently I am unaware of any desktop page layout apps - InDesign, Illustrator, Quark - that output xml/plist that can be ingested and mapped to CoreText.

Can someone suggest a solution? What approach are folks out there currently using for CoreText?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are parsing XHTML in our app (vg+). http://itunes.apple.com/no/app/vg/id405708242

Comment: @Fossil Meh. Sigh, yes there is always HTML. Still early days in CoreText land. Thanks. Cheers. @dugla